# Session id in url

Tags: php, session, sessionid

I made a site in php and when i visit it it shows a session id in the url.

http://pandhuishaaglanden.nl/wat_wij_verkopen.php?PHPSESSID=f4d91f171d85b4ccabbb8d06e29b7308

I dont know why or how, because google sees this a duplicate content in the SEO standaards.

Can someone please tell me what or how this is.

Comment: What are your session settings in your php.ini?

Comment: Thats to support browsers with deactivated cookies / without cookie support. PHP also supports session authentication via URL parameter (with `session.use_only_cookies` set to `0`) instead of a cookie.

Comment: @LouisH. put that down as an answer instead, it's correct.

Comment: Sorry im new to php how can i change this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats to support browsers with deactivated cookies / without cookie support. PHP also supports session authentication via URL parameter (with `session.use_only_cookies` set to `0`) instead of a cookie.

To disable it set `session.use_trans_sid` to `0` with [ini_set](http://ch2.php.net/ini_set). You also might wanna set `session.use_only_cookies` to `1` to be sure `PHPSESSID` in URL won't be used at all.

Comment: okey this make sense but how do i change it so that it will not show the sesssion id in the url anymore

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to your .htacess file:

`php_flag session.use_trans_sid off`